# Enable checkboxes with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I need your help for a simple jQuery script. I have some images with a surrounding a-tag. Next to the images, there are some checkboxes. My goal is, to enable and disable special checkboxes with a click on an image.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post the code?

Answer (score 0):

```
<img id="img_1" src="http://lorempixel.com/20/20/">
<input id="cb_1" type="checkbox" >

$("#img_1").click(function(){
   $("#cb_1").prop("disabled", !$("#cb_1").prop("disabled"));
});
```

This will toggle the disabled state by clicking on your image.

https://jsfiddle.net/fxa6894d/

If you only want to disable the checkbox you can use:

```
$("#img_1").click(function(){
   $("#cb_1").prop("disabled", true);
});
```

and to enable it you can use:

```
$("#img_1").click(function(){
   $("#cb_1").prop("disabled", false);
});
```

If you want to toggle the `checked` property you can use:

```
$("#img_1").click(function(){
   $("#cb_1").prop("checked", !$("#cb_1").prop("checked"));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fxa6894d/2/

Comment: Thank you for your code, but can you edit it, so that i can enable it too?

Comment: @MatthiasM clicking the image again will toggle the state. I have updated the answer to show how to only enable/disable the checkbox.

Comment: thanks again. My problem is that now the checkbox is not active (no check inside the square) but clickable and not clickable with your code

Comment: Do you want the checkbox to be checked if it's enabled and unchecked when it's disabled? Your original question is just about enabling/disabling a checkbox. I have updated the answer again and added another jsfiddle link to show how to toggle the `checked` state when you click on the image. If you want, you can combine enabling/disabling and checking/unchecking as you please. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it answers your question. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#img_id").click(function()
{
  $("#checkbox_id")..prop( "checked", true );
});
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?